# Why is sbt not finding my dependency?

Tags: sbt, sonatype

In the build.sbt for my lift project, I have a dependency on the paypal library

```
"net.liftmodules" % "paypal_2.6" % "1.3-SNAPSHOT",
```

At build time (e.g. sbt compile), the module cannot be found. What is confusing me is that if I check in the sonatype repo, the expected dependency is there

http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/net/liftmodules/paypal_2.6_2.11/1.3-SNAPSHOT/paypal_2.6_2.11-1.3-SNAPSHOT.pom

My question is why is sbt not finding a dependency that clearly exists>

```
  [info] Resolving net.liftmodules#paypal_2.6_2.11;1.3-SNAPSHOT ...
[warn]  module not found: net.liftmodules#paypal_2.6_2.11;1.3-SNAPSHOT
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\Andrew Bucknell\.ivy2\local\net.liftmodules\paypal_2.6_2.11\1.3-SNAPSHOT\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/liftmodules/paypal_2.6_2.11/1.3-SNAPSHOT/paypal_2.6_2.11-1.3-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== snapshots: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/liftmodules/paypal_2.6_2.11/1.3-SNAPSHOT/paypal_2.6_
2.11-1.3-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== releases: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/net/liftmodules/paypal_2.6_2.11/1.3-SNAPSHOT/paypal_2.6_2
.11-1.3-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.liftmodules/paypal_2.6_2.11/1.3-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== snapshots: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/liftmodules/paypal_2.6_2.11/1.3-SNAPSHOT/paypal_2.6_
2.11-1.3-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== staging: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/staging/net/liftmodules/paypal_2.6_2.11/1.3-SNAPSHOT/paypal_2.6_2.
11-1.3-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== releases: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/net/liftmodules/paypal_2.6_2.11/1.3-SNAPSHOT/paypal_2.6_2
.11-1.3-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my sonatype resolvers to use https

```
resolvers ++= Seq("snapshots"     at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots",
                "releases"        at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"
                )
```

problem solved.